# Detecting Events in time series

Tags: time-series-analysis

I am working with a time series which is, in fact a pressure signal.
There are special "events" in the signal that I am looking for.for example where the signal suddenly goes up or down or where there is an abrupt peak in the signal.I have shown some of them with red arrows in the picture.
I am familiar (but not an expert) in the field of data science and machine leaning. What is the best way to use AI techniques to automatically detect and classify these events?
Thanks in advance!
[image: some of events that I am looking for]

Comment: What makes you think you need artificial intelligence or machine learning to solve this problem? A simple threshold in the first differences of a small window average will pick out all of these peaks no problem.

Comment: You can try [dsp.se].